# slice the dataframe into intervals for statistical analysis | python

Tags: python, json, pandas, statistics, dataframe

I'm lost with one exercise, where I need to aggregate different features of dataframe for every session, given between some datetime points, so that the final data would have the following format:

```
          {'Sessions': [{'SessionId':'<Int>', 'MaxNote':'<Int>', 
            'groups': [{'groupId':'Int', 
        'Students':[{'studentId':<Int>,   'date':'datetime', 'MaxEnglishNote':'<Int>',
      'Math':'<Int>', 'Philosophy':'<Int>'}, 
            {'studentId':<Int>, 'date':'datetime', 'MaxEnglishNote':'<Int>', 
    'Math':'<Int>', 'Philosophy':'<Int>'}]},
            {'groupId':'Int', 'Students':
            [{'studentId':<Int>, 'date':'datetime', 'MaxEnglishNote':'<Int>',
 'Math':'<Int>', 'Philosophy':'<Int>'},
             {'studentId':<Int>, 'date':'datetime','MaxEnglishNote':'<Int>',
 'Math':'<Int>', 'Philosophy':'<Int>'}]}]}
```

What I made is a creation the json-like object where I stored these sessions, but the next ensuing transformations and aggregation the values with unique ID, seem to be difficult. note, that all the values associated to the unique StudentID happen at the same time that the StudentID
so I asked for your advice: should I stock the sessions-intervals in other form, more suitable for iterating over the rows, aggregation etc, or there solution for iterating over the nested lists in json-like object ? 
final result that I'de like to achieve is flat dictionary for different statistic and ml tasks

so json-like object that I actually have is like:

```
 [[{'date':'2013-10-09 09:00:00', 'value':'545747', 'field':'GroupeID'},
     {'date':'2013-10-09 09:00:00',  'value':'66463', 'field': 'StudentID'},
     {'date':'2013-10-09 09:00:00' , 'value':'197290' ,'field': 'Philosophy'},
    {'date':'2013-10-09 09:90:00','value':'470186' , 'field':'EnglishBegin'},
    {'date':'2013-10-09 09:00:00' , 'value':'470186' , 'field': 'EnglishEnd'},
     {'date':'2013-10-09 09:00:00' , 'value':'470186', 'field': 'EnglishMiddle'},
     {'date':'2013-10-09 09:00:00' , 'value':'181314' , 'field': 'Math'},
    {'date':'2013-10-09 09:35:00',  'value':'969427' ,'field': 'StudentID'},
    {'date':'2013-10-09 09:35:00' , 'value':'65645' , 'field':'EnglishEnd'},
     {'date':'2013-10-09 09:35:00' , 'value':'45433' , 'field':'EnglishMiddle'},
       {'date':'2013-10-09 09:35:00' , 'value':'181314' ,'field': 'Math'}
   {'date':'2013-10-09 09:35:00' , 'value':'003698' , 'field':'Philosphie'}],
   [{...},

         ......
```

that I get from the data-frame with columns ; date, field, value, with following code:

```
def create_interval():
    intervales=[]
    for index, row in bounds.iterrows():
        s = row['date_start']
        e = row['date_end']
        mask = (df['date'] > s) & (df['date'] < e)
        df_interval=df.loc[mask]
        intervales.append([{k:df_interval.values[i][v] for v,k in  enumerate(df_interval.columns)} for i in range(len(df_interval))])

    return intervales
```

So if you have idea how could I store the `df_interval` for best parsing and analysis , it could considerably help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have relational data and want to perform aggregations. What about using a relational database with the appropriate model to link everything together and compute the aggregations?

Answer (score 0):

after have found this question and answers for them on StackExchange
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235707/using-a-relational-database-vs-json-objects-for-event-activity-data

I realized that staying on dataframes with pandas instead of using json-objects could be the best solution for the type of data I have